# Как в AndroidStudio контролировать уровень использования памяти устройства?

Tags: java, android, outofmemoryerror

Программа выводит на экран игровую графику. При использовании эмулятора AndroidStudio ошибок не появляется. Если запускаю программу на смартфоне через промежуток времени получаю ошибку "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 576012 byte allocation with 45128 free bytes and 44KB until OOM" Насколько я могу понять программе не хватает оперативной памяти. При чём эта ошибка появляется после команды загрузки графического изображения в память

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromType() {
    bitmapScale = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID);
    bitmapScale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapScale, (int) (pixelPerBall * NUMBER_FRAME_ANIMATION), (int) (pixelPerBall), false);
    return bitmapScale;
}
```

Все изображения, которые могут быть загружены в программу, в сумме занимают 1Мб. Я считаю, что это не много. Откуда может появится ошибка переполнения?
Подскажите, можно ли как-то в процессе выполнения программы в AndroidStudio контролировать уровень используемой памяти, чтобы понять из-за каких действий программы уровень используемой памяти превышает допустимый? Как поступают в подобных случаях с нехваткой памяти?

Comment: Размер в пикселях у изображений какой?

Comment: @andreymal, размер 640*64

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/measure-and-optimize-bitmap-size-using-glide-or-picasso-3273b4a569cd